# Repeated calls to JNI method crashes the application

Tags: android, memory-management, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So I noticed that my app crashes after repeated calls of the following method.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_kitware_VolumeRender_VolumeRenderLib_DummyFunction(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj, jlong udp, jdoubleArray rotation, jdoubleArray translation){
  jboolean isCopy1, isCopy2 ;
  jdouble* rot = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(rotation,&isCopy1);
  jdouble* trans = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(translation,&isCopy2);

  if(isCopy1 == JNI_TRUE){
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(rotation,rot, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  if(isCopy2 == JNI_TRUE){
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(translation,trans, JNI_ABORT);
  }

}
```

I thought this would be due to some missing memory space but I do free the memory here don't I? Still after 512 calls to that method I get my app crashing.

I could provide you with the `Logcat` if needed but it's a pretty long one. And after investigating a little I'm pretty sure the error is in the memory allocation/free process (i.e commenting out the two `GetDoubleArrayElements()` get me a running app no matter how many times I call the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

it is clearly stated:

> **You must Release every array you Get**. Also, if the Get call fails, you must ensure that your code doesn't try to Release a NULL pointer later.

the number 512 is as far as I remember a limit on the number of local references which your code exceeds. So you should remove those checks: `if(isCopy2 == JNI_TRUE){`.

Still, above docs has a paragraph on JNI_ABORT, which explains it might be used together with isCopy - but its a bit confusing. You might search android sources on how to use JNI_ABORT, ie here is some code:

http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/ml/bordeaux/learning/multiclass_pa/jni/jni_multiclass_pa.cpp#77

In my code I often use PushLocalFrame/PopLocalFrame to prevent local references leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Definitely helps to release them anyway. So from what I read and if I understood correctly, a good way to do it would be: `if(isCopy1 == JNI_TRUE){
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(rotation,rot, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  else{
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(rotation,rot, 0);
  }
  if(isCopy1 == JNI_TRUE){
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(translation,trans, JNI_ABORT);
  }
  else{
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(translation,trans, 0);
  }` am I right? If I am you may want to add it to your answer. Anyway anser accepted and upvoted for the doc and advice.

Comment: @LBes I would say that there is no point in checking  isCopy here, if you look into sources: http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/art/runtime/jni_internal.cc#ReleasePrimitiveArray, you will see that this function is not checking mode for JNI_ABORT when isCopy==false, you will also see that in case if isCopy is false, then this function executes in some cases following method: DecrementDisableMovingGC